# Regex to find all hrefs that contain a path but no "." (dot)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm a newbie
I am trying to create a regex in notepad ++ to replace all `href="http://www.reactivemail.com/(any series of charcters)"`

essentially all I want is to put a / on the end of all href's but only if it does not contain a dot e.g it is a path to a file like .html

so here is what i want to find

`href="http://www.reactivemail.com(some path to a directory)"`

but ignore `href="http:www.reactivemail.com(some path).some extension"`

and want to add a / to href's that only go to a directory and are missing a / on the end

this is the regex I am using:

```
(href="http:\/\/www\.reactivemail\.com[^\.*.*"*]*)
```

and the replace is `\1/`

it finds what I want perfectly

only for href's with a .file extension it still finds the path and ignores everything after the. instead of ignoring everything because it contains a dot

Comment: What if a directory name contains a dot?

Comment: no directorys do contain a dot i tried your solution though and it does not work as it finds everything till the end of the line 
e.g href="http://www.reactivemail.com/pricing"><span>pricing</span>
instead of just href="http://reactivemail.com/pricing

however it does ingore everything with a dot in it

I wouldn't be bother if there were not 500 or so links that needed updating

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit dangerous (see my comment to your question), but you can try searching for:

```
(href="http://www.reactivemail.com/[^."]*[^/])"
```

and replacing with

```
\1/"
```

Comment: More precisely: replace `(href="http:\/\/www\.reactivemail\.com[^.]*[^/])(")` with `\1/"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
`(http[s]*\://[^\"]+)/([^\."/]+)"`
and replace with `\1/\2/"`. This should catch every http and https url, but will miss the folders with periods in them.